# Is it possible to refactor these two similar methods that handle T and List<T>?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to unify or refactor two methods that do basically the same but the difference being of handling a type of object or a collection of the same type of object?

The following is an implementation of two methods that have very similar behavior. They handle a cache for an API, so when someone asks for a value or a set of values, it verifies that the entry is in cache already. If not, they call the method that will return from an external API: a value or a set of values. Finally the methods, update the cache and return the value/values.

```
public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getItem, MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null)
{
    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out T cacheEntry))
    {
        return cacheEntry;
    }
    else
    {
        cacheEntry = await getItem();

        return SetValue(cacheKey, cacheEntry, memoryCacheEntryOptions);
    }
}

public async Task<IList<T>> GetValues<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<IList<T>>> getItems, MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null)
{
    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out IList<T> cacheEntries))
    {
        return cacheEntries;
    }
    else
    {
        cacheEntries = await getItems();

        return SetValues(cacheKey, cacheEntries, memoryCacheEntryOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Guys the code is compiling. If it does not compile (it does) you can abstract the idea of the methods.

Comment: Syntax option: `public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getItem, MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null) => _memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out T cacheEntry) ? cacheEntry : SetValue(cacheKey, await getItem(), memoryCacheEntryOptions);`

Comment: Btw, `GetValue<T>` would be enough, as it can do the job for `GetValues<T>`, look: `public Task<IList<T>> GetValues<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<IList<T>>> getItems, MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null) => GetValue(cacheKey, getItems, memoryCacheEntryOptions);`

Comment: @aepot Wooow! How is it possible that getValue can return a List<T> and T at the same time?!!

Comment: Because `T` isn't a type name but like a placeholder for any real type. With generic type you tell compiler "I don't know the real type but it will be the same type here, here and here". T and T is the same type, the same for `List<T>`. But you can drop details about `IList` because you don't use the interface methods which `IList` provides. Then `IList` can be just a `T`.

Comment: Awesome, so I can use T to represent a T, IList<T>, IList<IList<T>>, etc as long as I don't use methods from IList. And if I do, I can do what @Kevin answered. Thanks, I learned something really useful!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but the first thing that leapt to mind is:

```
<T> can encompass a IList<SomeType> already.
```

I mean, the first 75% of GetValue() *already works* with using IList as the generic type:

```
public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(
        string cacheKey,
        Func<Task<T>> getItem,
        MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null)
{
    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out T cacheEntry))
    {
        return cacheEntry;
    }
    else
    {
        cacheEntry = await getItem(); 

        return SetValue(cacheKey, cacheEntry, memoryCacheEntryOptions);
    }
}
```

... `memoryCache.TryGetValue()` works exactly the same, and will operate correctly.  `cacheEntry` will be the correct type (an `IList` of something.)  `getItem()` works perfectly, too, since it's a `Func` that returns the appropriate `IList`.

Literally the only thing that's different is `SetValue` vs `SetValues`.  Which, from your original post, looks to be the call into the 3rd party API.

Well, it begs the question of whether `SetValue()` in the vendor API will work for an `IList`?
If it does, your probably is immediately solved: just use `GetValue` for everything and call it a day.

Assuming that it doesn't, maybe the question would be whether something like this would work:

```
public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getItem, MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null)
{
    return GetValue(cacheKey, getItem, x => SetValue(cacheKey, x, memoryCacheEntryOptions));
}
public async Task<T> GetValues<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getItem, MemoryCacheEntryOptions memoryCacheEntryOptions = null)
{
    return GetValue(cacheKey, getItem, x => SetValues(cacheKey, x, memoryCacheEntryOptions));
}

private async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getItem, Func<T, Task<T>> setItem)
{
    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out T cacheEntry))
    {
        return cacheEntry;
    }
    else
    {
        cacheEntry = await getItem(); 

        return setItem(cacheEntry);
    }
}
```